# How do I correctly write a sub-query to get count of comments for each post?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to return a sqlite3 query that will allow me to loop through social media posts and display the post and user details and the number of comments on each post.

I can't figure out how to write a sql query that gets the number of comments for the post.

Here is my database scheme in ERD:

[image]

And here is my query:

```
SELECT u.name, u.icon, p.date, p.title, p.message,
       (SELECT comment.postId, COUNT(comment.Id) 
        FROM comment
        WHERE comment.postID = p.Id) as commentno
FROM Post p, User u
WHERE p.userID = u.Id
```

What I see when I try to run this:

> Error: sub-select returns 2 columns - expected 1

What I want to see:

```
Michael Scott, Michael.png, 2019-08-27, "Blog title", "Blog message", 7
```

Comment: Read the error message. In your sub query, you have two columns `comment.postId` and `COUNT(comment.Id)` and you are assigning a single alias `commentno` to that. I don't think that was your intention.

Comment: You just need to remove `comment.postId,` from your subquery. But you should also write your `JOIN` explicitly i.e. `FROM Post p JOIN User u ON p.userID = u.Id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment above. I think you intended this:

```
    SELECT u.name, u.icon, p.date, p.title, p.message,
       c.postId, COUNT(c.Id) as commentno             
        FROM Post p LEFT JOIN  User u ON p.userID = u.Id
        LEFT JOIN Comment c on p.ID = c.PostID
        GROUP BY  u.name, u.icon, p.date, p.title, p.message, c.postId
```

**UPDATE**
As was pointed out, my original answer had the same error (because I just quickly moved the alias. Here I reformatted your query to use `JOINs`. I assumed that your `Post` table has a comment ID, but you can figure out the appropriate columns for your `JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks @Nick. I should have paid more attention before I answered. I also "fixed" the implied `JOINs` this time.

Comment: The current version has all sorts of errors. I'm quite amazed that OP has accepted it.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce these errors, @Nick. It shows me the expected result, and doesn't throw any errors in SQLite 3. But maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @luknuk the query as it currently stands has a syntax error due to the third line  which should not be there. It also is missing a `GROUP BY` clause and probably (dependent on your requirements) a `WHERE/HAVING` clause as well. WIth minimal data in your table (only one user and post) it will give the correct result, but once you add more users and posts it will stop working.

Comment: @Nick Thank you for your help. Would you say my query should be looking like this? 

`SELECT u.name, u.icon, p.date, p.title, p.message,

            (SELECT COUNT(comment.Id) FROM comment GROUP BY postID HAVING postId = p.Id) as commentno

        FROM Post p, User u

        WHERE p.userID = u.Id`

Comment: Now there are mismatched parenthesis.  Why remove the nested SELECT but leave the FROM clause?

Comment: I need to stop editing while multitasking! Thanks to @CPerkins and Nick for pointing out the errors.

Comment: @daShier Your query works, but it only returns one row.

Comment: @luknuk I added the `GROUP BY` clause.